# change only part of the substring using sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a file that contains numbers copied from somewhere.
It looks something like this:

```
{02   12     04 01 07 10 11 06 08 05 03    15     13     00    14     09},
{14   11     02 12 04 07 13 01 05 00 15    10     03     09    08     06},
{04   02     01 11 10 13 07 08 15 09 12    05     06     03    00     14},
{11   08     12 07 01 14 02 13 06 15 00    09     10     04    05     03}
```

I now have to add comma after every number
(basically to make it a C++ array).
I tried using sed:

```
cat file.txt | sed -r "s/ /, /g"
```

But this prefixes every space with a comma,
while I only want them after digits.

If I use `cat file.txt | sed -r "s/[0123456789] /, /g"`,
I won't be able to get the same number before replacement.
Thus, I only want to change some part of the substring.

How do I do this?

Comment: @Hello scipsycho. Please see below. is this what you want?

Comment: Just a heads-up: It won't compile even with commas. `08` and `09` are not valid integer literals.

Comment: @pipe you are right! but now that you guys have answered this question, I will do `cat file.txt | sed -r 's/([{, ])0+([0-9])+/ \1 \2/g'` which will remove any zeros occurring in the units place

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cat file.txt | sed -r 's/([0-9]+)/\1,/g'

{02,   12,     04, 01, 07, 10, 11, 06, 08, 05, 03,    15,     13,     00,    14,     09,},
{14,   11,     02, 12, 04, 07, 13, 01, 05, 00, 15,    10,     03,     09,    08,     06,},
{04,   02,     01, 11, 10, 13, 07, 08, 15, 09, 12,    05,     06,     03,    00,     14,},
{11,   08,     12, 07, 01, 14, 02, 13, 06, 15, 00,    09,     10,     04,    05,     03,}
```

Explanation:

```
First capturing group ([0-9]+)

Match a single character (i.e. number) present in the table [0-9]+ 
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)

In other words, the [0-9]+ pattern matches an integer number (without decimals) even Inside longer strings, even words.
\1 is called a "back reference" or "special escapes" in the sed documentation. It refers to the corresponding matching sub-expressions in the regexp. In other words, in this example, it inserts the contents of each captured number in the table followed by comma.
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked! What does this '\1' mean?

Comment: Hi @scipsycho. ` \1` refers to the number within each cell in the field will be followed by a comma. :-)

Comment: So, those brackets tell sed what to include in '\1', right?

Comment: Dear @scipsycho kindly see my edits and let me know if you need further explanation ;-)

Comment: Hi @Goro, thanks a lot for this explanation.

Comment: The `\1` is called a "back reference" in the `sed` documentation.

Comment: `sed` can read files.

Answer (score 3):

You can just replace a space followed by any number of spaces by a comma:

```
sed 's/  */,/g' file
```

(if the spaces at the start of some lines are just a copy paste error)

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
sed 's/ \+/, /g' file
{02, 12, 04, 01, 07, 10, 11, 06, 08, 05, 03, 15, 13, 00, 14, 09},
{14, 11, 02, 12, 04, 07, 13, 01, 05, 00, 15, 10, 03, 09, 08, 06},
{04, 02, 01, 11, 10, 13, 07, 08, 15, 09, 12, 05, 06, 03, 00, 14},
{11, 08, 12, 07, 01, 14, 02, 13, 06, 15, 00, 09, 10, 04, 05, 03}
```

Answer (score 1):

This perl command will add a comma in between a digit and a space

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=\d)(?=\s)/,/g' file
```